# Convert html to text in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**HTML**

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>this is <br></p>
<p>a <br></p>
<p>test message</p><br>
```

I have already tried 'strip tags' which gives me the following output :
  "Hellothis is a test message"

**The output I want:**

```
Hello

this is 

a

test message
```

Comment: use html_safe after string.

Comment: tried that it gives the same string back! i want a text which strips the html at the same time displays the paragraphs on new line

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read  "[ask]" and "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code you need to show us the minimum code that demonstrates the problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the solution for you.

Answer (score 8):

```
html = "<p>Hello</p>
<p>this is <br></p>
<p>a <br></p>
<p>test message</p><br>"
```

## strip_tags

[`strip_tags`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags) helper seems to work fine :

```
puts ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(html)
# => 
# Hello
# this is 
# a 
# test message
```

## Nokogiri

[`Nokogiri`](http://www.nokogiri.org/) is included by default in Rails, so you could also use :

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.xpath("//text()").to_s
```

It outputs :

```
Hello
this is 
a 
test message
```

## Convert newlines to spaces

If you want to remove newlines :

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(html).gsub(/\s+/,' ')
#=> "Hello this is a test message"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ! i tried your above solution,unfortunately it is not giving me the desired output ,for this html string "<p>Heelo</p><p>this</p><p>is </p><p>a </p><p>test</p>message<br>" the output i am getting is "Heelothisis a testmessage"

Comment: What's the desired output, exactly?

Comment: i want all the words to come in a new line since all of them are in paragraph tag

Comment: They're in 4 separate tags though. I'll update the answer.

Comment: i am trying to send an email with both html and text format. For the html format i have used the html_safe option which works like a charm. but i want the same format to be displayed in the text email also .right now the string is shown in one line.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is rendered by a browser like:

```
Hello

this is 

a 

test message
```

This isn't quite correct though, because the HTML contains trailing `<br>` tags in the `<p>` tags, which should be a string like:

```
this is \n\n\n
```

which is normally considered a paragraph plus a new-line. But, browsers play games when rendering text in order to make it more readable, and gobble blank lines and spaces. For example, this HTML:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>bar</p>
```

renders as:

```
foo

bar
```

and:

```
<p>foo       bar</p>
```

renders as:

```
foo bar
```

So, you have to decide do you want to render the text using Nokogiri like the browser for readability, or do it accurately?

This does it like the browser:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p>Hello</p>
<p>this is <br></p>
<p>a <br></p>
<p>test message</p><br> 
EOT

doc.search('br').remove
text = doc.search('p').map { |p| p.text + "\n\n" }
puts text

# >> Hello
# >> 
# >> this is 
# >> 
# >> a 
# >> 
# >> test message
# >>
```

It removes the breaks, then converts the `<p>` contained text by appending two new-lines.

Doing it accurately, as per how the markup shows, is a little different:

```
doc.search('br').map { |br| br.replace("\n") }
text = doc.search('p').map { |p| p.text + "\n\n" }
puts text

# >> Hello
# >> 
# >> this is 
# >> 
# >> 
# >> a 
# >> 
# >> 
# >> test message
# >>
```

This is just a simplified way of doing it to get you started. Rails does the opposite of this in ActionView's [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) method.

Browsers have a lot more rules used to determine when and how to display the text and their rendering can be influenced by CSS and JavaScript which won't necessarily translate to text, especially plain text.